# Compare two arrays of a different type, print element in the same "slot" Java

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, user-input

so i am working on comparing two arrays based on a users input. One array is an int array, the other is a string. What i want to do is take a users input, compare the input to the first int array, then calculate the element within the same position of the string array. then print out my results based on the second array. 
Like below i would input 12 then get bob or 21 then get andrea. Example code below. I have everything up to the comparison of the second array (i have the user input, finding it within the int array - the loop, but i just cant figure out the comparison to the second array)

```
int[] number = {12, 15, 19, 21}
String[] character = {bob, sally, james, andrea}
```

would i just compare both the arrays then save it in a new variable:

```
number = character
```

then print the new variables value?

thanks for the help. i have been searching everywhere for this one. mainly spend a day and a half on this website.

Comment: Haven't you tried yourself first ?

Comment: yes, quite a bit. thats why i am asking. hints are nice, i enjoy discovery based on direction.

Comment: Why not use a Map of number -> string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to *compare* anything to the second array: once you have the index of the matching element in the first array, simply use that index against the second array. That's all there is to it!

```
int[] number = {12, 15, 19, 21};
String[] character = {"bob", "sally", "james", "andrea"};
int userInput = ... // <<== You know how to do all that 
for (int i = 0 ; i != number.length ; i++) {
    if (number[i] == userInput) {
        // Element at index i is matching:
        System.out.println(character[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: now i am getting an:

Error: incomparable types: int and java.lang.String

when i try to compile.

Comment: this is the full code:

'import jpb.*;'

public class comparison {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
   
   //Prompt the user to enter an SSN and trim the input
   SimpleIO.prompt("Enter 12, 15, 19, 21: ");
   String userInput = SimpleIO.readLine();
   
int[] number = {12, 15, 19, 21};
String[] character = {"bob", "sally", "james", "andrea"};



for (int i = 0 ; i != number.length ; i++) {
    if (number[i] == character[i]) {
      
        // Element at index i is matching:
        System.out.println(character[i]);
        break;
    }
}

 }
 
}

Comment: @Acronis that's because you are trying to compare String value against an int.

Answer (score 2):

You can you use a `Map` here.

Instantiate and populate the map:

```
Map<Integer, String> numberToNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
numberToNameMap.put(12, "bob");
//...
```

And then do a lookup:

```
String name = numberToNameMap.get(inputNumber);
```